# ERROR : undefined reference to classname::member_variable

Tags: c++, static-members

Can't print value of static int variable

I want to check the value of static variable in this context.

I am using www.codechef.com/ide as IDE : C++14 (Gcc 6.3) as the Language + Compiler.

CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Demo_StaticVar
{
    public :
    static int a;

    Demo_StaticVar()
    {
      cout<<a<<endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
  Demo_StaticVar obj1;



  return 0;
}
```

ERROR:

> /home/ptnn1S/ccl6RBkR.o: In function `main':
>
> prog.cpp:(.text.startup+0xf): undefined reference to `Demo_StaticVar::a'
>    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: You declared the variable only and never defined it.

Comment: Ok , Thank you for response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static int a;
```

This **declares** the static variable. That tells the compiler that this field exists and would be of type `int`. This is useful information for compiling the code.

But the variable still needs to be **defined**. That is some translation unit(and exactly one translation unit) needs to allocate the memory for this variable. See [What is a "translation unit" in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c)

For other NITs of declaration and definition check this question: [What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)

As to the solution you need to add a definition as well outside the class:

```
int Demo_StaticVar::a;
int main(){
...
```

Code link: https://ideone.com/l7ie7p

Comment: Sir : 

Did you mean > 
A definition reserves the memory to make the variable existing. This has to happen exactly once before first access.

* Note :  A definition is a declaration unless: definition defines a static class data member  .

Kindly assist me a bit more > as for non static variable the above code is working fine .

Thank you

Comment: How do you define first access?
I meant exactly what I wrote. The definition should be present in exactly one translation unit (which I called module). Otherwise the linker would again complain.
BTW if my post answers your posted question can you please mark it as accepted?

Comment: Ok , Thank you for valuable assistance

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt :
When a data member is declared as static, only one copy of the data is maintained for all objects of the class.

Static data members are not part of objects of a given class type. As a result, the declaration of a static data member is not considered a definition.

Source : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1b5y48f.aspx